# How: django_manage in ansible with Python3

Tags: django, ansible

I'm following this for django manage.py module 
http://docs.ansible.com/django_manage_module.html

for e.g. one of my tasks  looks like -

```
- name: Django migrate
  django_manage: command=migrate
                 app_path={{app_path}}
                 settings={{django_settings}}
  tags:
    - django
```

this works perfectly fine with python2(default in ubuntu) but when I try with python3-django project it throws error

```
failed: [123.456.200.000] => (item=school) => {"cmd": "python manage.py makemigrations --noinput school --settings=myproj.settings.production", "failed": true, "item": "school", "path": "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games", "state": "absent", "syspath": ["/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1432039779.41-30449122707918", "/usr/lib/python2.7", "/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu", "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk", "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old", "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload", "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages", "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"]}
msg: 
:stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

from this error it seems Ansible bydefault uses Python2. can we change this to python3 or anyother workaround?

PS: pip freeze ensure that django 1.8 has installed (for python3 using pip3)

Suggestions:
when I run `ubuntu@ubuntu:/srv/myproj$ python3 manage.py migrate` it works fine. so I'm thinking of passing command directly
something like

```
 - name: Django migrate
   command: python3 manage.py migrate
   tags:
     - django
```

but how do I pass the project path or manage.py file's path, there is only an option to pass settings, something like  `--settings=myproject.settings.main`.

can we do by passing direct command?

Comment: If you're using a virtual environment, then using the `virtualenv` parameter would hopefully use the Python 3 interpreter in the virtual environment.

Comment: @Alasdair: No! I'm not using virtualenv. everything is systemwide. `sudo pip3 install <pkg_name>`

Comment: Yeah, I had guessed that when I saw `pip3` in your question, but decided to leave the comment anyway because it might help somebody else. Hope you figure out a solution.

Comment: on local machine I use virtualenv.   `virtaulenv -p python3 venv`  but on remote sever I do `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` and use `pip3 install xyz` directly because I dont need virtualenv in that machine.

Comment: For command there is `chdir` key you can use to cd in a directory before running the command

Answer (score 3):

From Ansible website http://docs.ansible.com/intro_installation.html

> Python 3 is a slightly different language than Python 2 and most Python programs (including Ansible) are not switching over yet. However, some Linux distributions (Gentoo, Arch) may not have a Python 2.X interpreter installed by default. On those systems, you should install one, and set the ‘ansible_python_interpreter’ variable in inventory (see Inventory) to point at your 2.X Python. Distributions like Red Hat Enterprise Linux, CentOS, Fedora, and Ubuntu all have a 2.X interpreter installed by default and this does not apply to those distributions. This is also true of nearly all Unix systems. If you need to bootstrap these remote systems by installing Python 2.X, using the ‘raw’ module will be able to do it remotely.

Answer (score 3):

If you edit the shebang in the Django manage.py file to be `#!/usr/bin/env python3` then you can ensure that python 3 will always be used to run your Django app.

Tried successfully with Ansible 2.3.0 and Django 1.10.5. YMMV

Answer (score 1):

Ansible is using `python` to run the django command: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/web_infrastructure/django_manage.py#L237

Your only solution is thus to override the executable that will be run, for instance by changing your PATH:

```
- file: src=/usr/bin/python3 dest=/home/user/.local/bin/python state=link
- name: Django migrate
  django_manage: command=migrate
                 app_path={{app_path}}
                 settings={{django_settings}}
  environment:
    - PATH: "/home/user/.local/bin/:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin"
```

Comment: This is not the case anymore. At this moment is line 259 with ./manage.py

Comment: Ha well... but then: can the problem from the OP still occur?